# Wifi stopped working: "Device not ready" in nm-applet not at startup but after some time of inactivity

Tags: networking, wireless

My problem is explained in the title.

I followed the steps of [this link](https://hackthestuff.com/article/wifi-networks-device-not-ready-error-solve-in-linux) to try and get it to work but it seems I have another problem as the wifi works flawlessly at startup. Some related info:

```bsh
robin@mydevice:~$ cat iwconfig_output.txt # When my device doesn't work anymore (device not ready).
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm  
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
robin@mydevice:~$ iwconfig # at startup when things work flawlessly
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"**personal info**"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.54 GHz  Access Point: **personal-info**
          Bit Rate=650 Mb/s   Tx-Power=24 dBm  
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.

robin@mydevice:~$ iwconfig # after I disconnected from network but things still work
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm  
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
         
docker0   no wireless extensions.
robin@mydevice:~$ rfkill
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

Edit: Ubuntu version

```
robin@mydevice:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Docker version:

```
robin@mydevice:~$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.12
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.15
 Git commit:        e91ed5707e
 Built:             Mon Mar 21 06:17:35 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
```

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu and what docker.

Comment: edited the question to include those.